What is the name of this adventure 2d game where you pick 3 characters in the beginning in a mythical/magical setting
I'm trying to find an old game... Here are some details:
Platform(s): PC / Win XP
Genre: Adventure
Estimated year of release: Around 2005 probably, possibly very late 1990s or early 2000s as well. I remember I last played it around 2007 or 2008
Graphics/art style: It was a medieval/fantasy game where characters were drawn in a cartoon art style but were not cartoony in the sense of having silly shapes or something.
Notable characters: I remember there was a pool of characters in the beginning from which you could choose 3 to play with for the rest of the game. I vividly remember there was a priest of some sort who was an old guy and he could heal, also I think there was a guy with a shot gun of some sort but I'm not 100% on that one. There were also others that I have slight memories of but I really can not remember clearly and I don't want to give false hints.
Notable gameplay mechanics: There was a map for each area, I believe there were 5 areas in total but I might be wrong. Each map had different spots kind of how Path of Exile's map works. When you pick a dot/spot you go into that.. level? And you see your three characters in 2D similar to the golden age super mario style. You could move your characters left or right but mostly right as that's how levels progressed. When you walk into an enemy combat begins. Your characters were placed one after the other and the rightmost one was taking almost all the damage since the enemy monsters were on the right. You could use the space bar to switch the order of your characters so as to pick which character takes damage from the enemy attacks. You could also put a rotation on your characters' skills but you couldn't cast them on command. Basically they would go on to fight the battle on their own and you didn't have much control over it except changing the order of your characters and the order of their spells which they would go on to rotate.
Other details: Also on each map there was a town where you could buy items for your characters. I believe the game name was consisted of 2 words which started with the same letter but I might be wrong on that. I also have a memory that it didn't sound like a typical game name but might be wrong on that also. I remember the first map was a green/grassy/forest kind of area where the last spot where the boss was had snow in it. The second map was a dark/cemetery themed where you had to fight spiders and I think some kind of zombies or something like that. Again those are 20ish year old memories so might be wrong on the numbering but trying to spit out everything I slightly remember.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
More info from the comments:

It was an executable windows game, not a browser game
It is not a popular game
We played it in a PC club at the time
Another thing I remembered, it had a very distinct music, not that it was anything special but it really stuck with you, kind of spooky and calm but intriguing at the same time, kinda hard to explain in words.


can you remember if you played it on an website or is an actual game (on disc or by download or other method)

@oelimoe yes, it is not a website game, we had it on a CD and it required an installation, but it is not any of the major titles.. It's a little known game, I realize the chance of finding it is pretty slim.

is there any reference material of an game with the same type of style(design) or might this lead in the wrong direction also try to ask this question on reddit/tipofmyjoystick

@oelimoe I tried already but as soon as I post my account gets banned and I am not sure why, perhaps new accounts can not post which is too sad because I'm not a reddit user.

also a good thing might you remember one of the logos of the game studios or game when the game started or something this might help since there are ALOT of games please also update the question with this info since not everyone reads the comments

@oelimoe not really, the slightest of memories that I have is regarding the name and is posted in the question. But it is quite a unique game, anyone who has played it will clearly know, otherwise as I said the chance of finding it is very slim as it wasn't really popular at all, we found it in a local PC club which we had at the time, who got it from god only knows where..

@oelimoe I've never heard or seen anyone play it or talk about it outside the PC club in question, even to this day. Surely there are many other people who have played it, what I'm trying to say is that it really wasn't a popular game.

Do you have any old screenshots or anything similar of this game? game-identification requests without specific media are off topic.

@qazmlpok sorry I wasn't aware but I happen to have found the game so I'm going to just post it as an answer in case anyone else is also looking for it in the future.

Thanks for adding the answer! Your question will still probably be closed, but it's always nice to see a self-answered [tag:game-identification] question.

@Schism Is it? Off-topic questions shouldn't really be answered.

Welcome to Arqade! Unfortunately, ID of games from memory & without media from the game itself is considered off-topic here. If you have a similar question in the future, our sister site [scifi.se] SE allows identification of games with a sci-fi/fantasy theme or similar elements. You might want to consider posting there next time, but be sure to check their ID guidelines first.

After spending about 10 hours, the game is The Spirit Engine.


I wasn't sure if you meant the first or the second one; I added a link and a screencap for the first one, but please edit/revert if you meant the other one!
